# Ra and Rb 555 Timer

Tags: resistors, 555

Frequency - 10.53 Hz
Duty Cycle - 52.63%
C2 - 100 uF (e12 value)
Time High - 49.97 ms
Time Low - 44.99 ms
Ra - ?
Rb - ?
please help me, people have offered websites but never what I need if you know how to solve please help thank you.

Comment: You asked the exact same question a few days ago. Deleting it and asking it again isn't going to win you any friends here.

Comment: this isn't eve a question.

Answer (score 3):

Any 555 calculator website can do this for you, but the results will be questionable.  To start, put in 10 K for Ra and 100K for Rb, and then adjust them until you get the output parameters you want.

Another approach is to use the equations in the 555 datasheet and calculate the resistor values directly.

BUT - your post indicates that you want results that are accurate to within 1 part in 5000.  That's 0.02%.  100 uF capacitors are not available with that tolerance.  Also, the three resistors inside a 555 that determine its inherent accuracy are nowhere near that precise.

Even if you use high precision resistors in series with small trimpots to tweak the circuit to exactly what you want, things will drift significantly with temperature changes in the room and with time as the components (especially the capacitor) age.